# Ordering data in R by the sum of a factor-associated numbers

Tags: r, dplyr

Thanks in advance for the help. I'm trying to order data by levels of one factor, and then by the sum of numeric data associated with another factor. Secondly, I'm trying to apply group numbers. I want to do this without manual input, such that a script can be saved for different, future data. To clarify, I've created an example dataset:

```
library(dplyr)

Year <- c("2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2020",
"2020", "2020", "2019", "2019", "2019", "2020", "2020", "2020", "2019", "2019", "2019")
Model <- factor(c("Mustang", "Mustang", "Mustang", "F150", "F150", "F150", "F150", "F150",
"F150", "Cruise", "Cruise", "Cruise", "Camaro", "Camaro", "Camaro", "Cruise",
"Cruise", "Cruise"))
Make <- factor(c("Ford", "Ford", "Ford", "Ford", "Ford", "Ford", "Ford", "Ford", "Ford",
"Chevy", "Chevy", "Chevy", "Chevy", "Chevy", "Chevy", "Toyota", "Toyota", "Toyota"),
levels = c("Ford", "Chevy", "Toyota"))
Color <- factor(c("Red", "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Blue", "Green",
"Red", "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Blue", "Green", "Red", "Blue", "Green"),
levels = c("Red", "Blue", "Green"))
Purchases <- c(20, 35, 10, 32, 49, 45, 37, 53, 25, 55, 24, 13, 32, 45, 60, 12, 20, 13)

Data <- data.frame(Year, Model, Make, Color, Purchases)

Data.order <- Data %>%
group_by(Make,Model) %>%
summarize(Sum=sum(Purchases)) %>%
arrange(Make,-Sum)
```

The 1st level of arrangement must be the Make, and then I want to re-order the Models according to the sum of purchases of the 3 different colors. Year is not relevant for ordering. I've attached a screenshot of the end goal. I also want to add group numbers (by Make/Model).

[image: Intended ordering]

**Progress/issue:** I've tried to sum and order the data into another data frame, and then reorder the levels of the primary data frame according to the new levels taken from the sum data frame, before arranging accordingly. This approach does not work because I have repeated levels in the Models from different Makes sharing the same Model name, "Cruise". Perhaps I can apply a consecutive group number sequence within the new Order data frame, and then cross-match the group numbers back to primary data frame to arrange by Type, Group number? Not sure how to do this

Thanks a lot everyone!!

Comment: Maybe this: `Data.order <- Data %>%
    group_by(Make,Model) %>%
    summarize(Sum=sum(Purchases)) %>% ungroup() %>%
    arrange(Make,desc(Sum))`

Comment: Hey @Duck, thanks for taking a look. I have that code in there already but the problem is with what to follow it with, to successfully rearrange and group-number the parent data frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the intention is to order the original dataset, create a sequence column after doing the `desc`ending arrange in 'Sum', then do a `left_join` and order based on the sequence column created

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>%
  group_by(Make,Model) %>%
  summarize(Sum=sum(Purchases), .groups = 'drop') %>%     
  arrange(Make, desc(Sum)) %>%      
  mutate(Group = row_number(), Sum  = NULL) %>%      
  left_join(Data) %>%
  arrange(Group) 
# A tibble: 18 x 6
#   Make   Model   Group Year  Color Purchases
#   <fct>  <fct>   <int> <chr> <fct>     <dbl>
# 1 Ford   F150        1 2019  Red          32
# 2 Ford   F150        1 2019  Blue         49
# 3 Ford   F150        1 2019  Green        45
# 4 Ford   F150        1 2020  Red          37
# 5 Ford   F150        1 2020  Blue         53
# 6 Ford   F150        1 2020  Green        25
# 7 Ford   Mustang     2 2019  Red          20
# 8 Ford   Mustang     2 2019  Blue         35
# 9 Ford   Mustang     2 2019  Green        10
#10 Chevy  Camaro      3 2020  Red          32
#11 Chevy  Camaro      3 2020  Blue         45
#12 Chevy  Camaro      3 2020  Green        60
#13 Chevy  Cruise      4 2019  Red          55
#14 Chevy  Cruise      4 2019  Blue         24
#15 Chevy  Cruise      4 2019  Green        13
#16 Toyota Cruise      5 2019  Red          12
#17 Toyota Cruise      5 2019  Blue         20
#18 Toyota Cruise      5 2019  Green        13
```

---

Or another option is to use `ave` within the `arrange` and then create the 'Group' column

```
Data %>% 
   arrange(Make, desc(ave(Purchases, Make, Model, FUN = sum))) %>% 
   group_by(Make, Model) %>%
   mutate(Group = cur_group_id())
# A tibble: 18 x 6
# Groups:   Make, Model [5]
#   Year  Model   Make   Color Purchases Group
#   <chr> <fct>   <fct>  <fct>     <dbl> <int>
# 1 2019  F150    Ford   Red          32     1
# 2 2019  F150    Ford   Blue         49     1
# 3 2019  F150    Ford   Green        45     1
# 4 2020  F150    Ford   Red          37     1
# 5 2020  F150    Ford   Blue         53     1
# 6 2020  F150    Ford   Green        25     1
# 7 2019  Mustang Ford   Red          20     2
# 8 2019  Mustang Ford   Blue         35     2
# 9 2019  Mustang Ford   Green        10     2
#10 2020  Camaro  Chevy  Red          32     3
#11 2020  Camaro  Chevy  Blue         45     3
#12 2020  Camaro  Chevy  Green        60     3
#13 2019  Cruise  Chevy  Red          55     4
#14 2019  Cruise  Chevy  Blue         24     4
#15 2019  Cruise  Chevy  Green        13     4
#16 2019  Cruise  Toyota Red          12     5
#17 2019  Cruise  Toyota Blue         20     5
#18 2019  Cruise  Toyota Green        13     5
```